# How do I check if the sum of values of 2 columns is greater than a number and update table

Tags: php, mysql

```
    CREATE TABLE candidate_subjects
    (
    id INT(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    candidate_id INT(11),
    exam_type_id INT(10),
    subject_id INT(10),
    ca_score INT(11),
    exam_score INT(6),
    score_grade VARCHAR(10),
    date_created VARCHAR(10),
    date_modified TIMESTAMP
    );

    INSERT INTO `candidate_subjects` (`id`, `candidate_id`, `exam_type_id`, 
    `subject_id`, `ca_score`, `exam_score`, `score_grade`, `date_created`, 
    `date_modified`) VALUES
    (1, 2, 1, 32, 22, 61, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:10:33'),
    (2, 2, 1, 5, 21, 38, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:10:33'),
    (3, 2, 1, 14, 21, 51, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:10:33'),
    (4, 2, 1, 1, 19, 34, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:10:33'),
    (5, 2, 1, 2, 23, 39, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:10:33'),
    (6, 2, 1, 38, 20, 32, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:10:33'),
    (7, 2, 1, 53, 24, 47, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:10:33'),
    (8, 4, 1, 32, 19, 61, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:27'),
    (9, 4, 1, 5, 22, 41, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:27'),
    (10, 4, 1, 14, 20, 46, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:27'),
    (11, 4, 1, 1, 23, 37, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:27'),
    (12, 4, 1, 2, 21, 36, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:27'),
    (13, 4, 1, 38, 22, 34, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:27'),
    (14, 4, 1, 53, 24, 52, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:27'),
    (15, 5, 1, 32, 20, 62, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:44'),
    (16, 5, 1, 5, 22, 38, NULL, '2017-02-01', '2017-08-28 13:11:44’);


    CREATE TABLE candidates
    (
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    exam_no VARCHAR(15),
    surname VARCHAR(50),
    other_names VARCHAR(100),
    school_id INT(11),
    registration_completed INT(11),
    exam_scores_completed INT(5),
    remark VARCHAR(10)
    );
```

INSERT INTO `candidates` (`id`, `exam_no`, `surname`, `other_names`, `school_id`, `registration_completed`, `exam_scores_completed`, `remark`) VALUES
(1, '1171052001', 'ABADO', 'MASENENGEN', 1052, 1, '1', ''),
(2, '1170938001', 'AGBA', 'NGUHER', 938, 1, '1', ''),
(3, '1170071001', 'ABEE', 'SESUUR', 71, 1, '1', ''),
(4, '1170938002', 'AHEN', 'REBECCA DOOSUUN', 938, 1, '1', ''),

The two tables above are candidates and candidate_subjects for storing candidate details and candidate scores respectively.
I want a query to update candidate remark to 'FAIL' if the candidate pass less than 6 subjects. To pass a subject, the candidate sum of ca_score and exam_score for a subject must be greater than 40.
Below is the query I have written but it is not giving the result expected.

```
    UPDATE candidates SET candidates.remark='FAIL' WHERE (select 
    count(candidate_subjects.id) AS total_pass from candidates, 
    candidate_subjects where candidates.id=candidate_subjects.candidate_id 
    and (candidate_subjects.ca_score + candidate_subjects.exam_score) >= 40) < 6
```

Comment: Format your code as readable

Comment: Provide sample data for candidates table also

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid sample data for candidates table provided

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE candidates 
SET candidates.remark='FAIL' 
WHERE id IN
(

    select candidates.id
    from candidates AS c
    INNER JOIN candidate_subjects AS s ON c.id = s.candidate_id 
    WHERE (s.ca_score + s.exam_score) >= 40
    GROUP BY c.id
    HAVING COUNT(s.id) < 6
)
```

- The subquery in the where clause, with `group by` candidate id, will give you those candidates with scores larger than 40.
- Then `having` will remove all the rows expect those with with subjects less than six subjects.